# Google cloud dns CNAME creation example

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I had been not able to create a new CNAME for a specific managed-zone.

I can see there are examples for A and TXT entries like:

```
$ gcloud dns record-sets transaction add -z MANAGED_ZONE \
            --name my.domain. --ttl 1234 --type A "1.2.3.4"

$ gcloud dns record-sets transaction add -z MANAGED_ZONE \
            --name my.domain. --ttl 2345 --type TXT "Hello world" "Bye \
            world"
```

But I keep getting *too few arguments* error.
Currently I'm issuing:

```
$ gcloud dns record-sets -z=MYZONE transaction add\
            --name="NAME" --type=CNAME --ttl 3600 --rrdatas="DEST"
```

I guess the issue is related to the rrdatas field but I have been unable to find any documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The command does not have a `rrdatas` flag. You can just put the value you want for `rrdatas` at the end of the command as a positional argument. Also, note that the `-z` zone flag should be provided after all the commands. So:

```
$ gcloud dns record-sets -z=MYZONE transaction add --type=CNAME \
  --name="www.example.com." --ttl 3600 --rrdatas="target.example.com."
```

should be changed to this:

```
$ gcloud dns record-sets transaction add -z=MYZONE --type=CNAME \
  --name="www.example.com." --ttl 3600 "target.example.com."
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [record types](https://cloud.google.com/dns/what-is-cloud-dns#supported_record_types) documented on the API, note that the *rrdatas* value should point to a valid record or must end with periods (.) in the case of fully-qualified DNS names.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and was able to create CNAME records with the following steps. You begin by starting a transaction:

`gcloud dns record-sets transaction start --zone=domain-com`

Then, add records to the transaction (add as many as you need):

`gcloud dns record-sets transaction add "subdomain.domain.com." --name="cnamelocation.com." --ttl=3600 --type=CNAME --zone=domain-com`

Lastly, execute the transaction:

`gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute --zone=domain-com`

If you mess up at some point along the way, you can abort the transaction and start over:

`gcloud dns record-sets transaction abort --zone=domain-com`